# How to effieicently set specific rows and columns of a sparse matrix to zero in Eigen

Tags: c++, for-loop, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have the following section of the code that seems to take awhile to perform. Basically based on the value of an array index, if the value is 1 or higher, then I want to set that element in the matrix to 1 and the rest of the elements of that specific row and column to zero. The size of my sparse matrix can sometimes to 15000. Wonder if there is a more effiecient way to perform this operation.

```
int count = 5000;

for(k=0;k<count*3;k+=3) {
    if(ones(k/3) > 0.99){
      for(l=0;l<count*3;l+=3) {
        if(k == l) {      
          sparseM.row(k) *= 0; 
          sparseM.col(k) *= 0; 
          sparseM.coeffRef(k,l) = 1;        

          sparseM.row(k+1) *= 0; 
          sparseM.col(k+1) *= 0; 
          sparseM.coeffRef(k+1,l+1) = 1;        

          sparseM.row(k+2) *= 0; 
          sparseM.col(k+2) *= 0; 
          sparseM.coeffRef(k+2,l+2) = 1;        
    }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: A problem is that Eigen uses either compress spare row or column format. For instance, if your matrix is stored in CSR, then you can quickly access individual rows. But to access all elements from a single column, you need to iterate over all the matrix elements.

Comment: I don't need to access all elements of the row and col. All I need is to set any non-zero elements to zero in that row/col

Comment: I understand. I just said that it likely cannot be too fast due to the problem I pointed to. You may try another approach — to build a lookup table of to-be-zeroed rows/columns and then to iterate over a matrix elements and check that table for each element. Whether this will be faster, who knows, you need to measure.

Comment: Or, if you have enough memory, I would suggest transforming the matrix into a dense format, then you can zero rows/columns super-efficiently, and finally, convert the matrix back into the sparse format. However, this is viable only if there is enough memory for storing the whole matrix as dense.

Comment: Have a look at [`prune`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#title29)

Comment: I did look at prune. My understadning is it removes the row/col. So I wont be able to have  a certain element as 1 in that row/col

Comment: The `KeepFunc` which you pass to `prune` is actually capable of changing the value it gets passed to (this requires that there already is an element at `(i,i)`). Alternativly, look at how that function is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time on this I think I have a solution that is much more efficient compared to my original post. Would like to know your comments. If you see any caveats...

```
    for (Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,Eigen::ColMajor>::InnerIterator it(sparseM, k); it; ++it){
      if(ones(it.row()) > 0.99){
        it.valueRef() = 0.0;
      }   
      if(ones(k) > 0.99){
        if(k == it.col()) { 
          if(it.row() == it.col()) {
            it.valueRef() = 1.0;
          } else {
            it.valueRef() = 0.0;          
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```